# Задержка события нажатия кнопки

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Имеется кнопка переключения загрузки страницы через парсер Jsoup. Если кнопку много раз нажать, собирается очередь и Jsoup по мере загрузки выдает каждый результат нажатия. Требуется: если кнопка нажимается часто (например чаще 1р в 1 сек), то событие не срабатывает. Если произошло нажатие и прошла 1 секунда, то событие срабатывает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как подобное можно реализовать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример реализации нажатия на кнопку "назад".

В переменный класса объявляем `private long back_pressed;`

Затем, создаем перехват нажатия:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            stopAllServices();
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Чтобы выйти, нажмите на кнопку НАЗАД ещё раз.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Answer (score 2):

1. заведите `long` переменную, в которой будет храниться `timeStamp` последнего нажатия.
2. При нажатии сравните текущее время со значением этой переменной.
3. Если разница больше 1000мс, то выполните запрос, иначе - ничего не делайте.
4. Сразу после вычисления разницы времени обновите значение переменной из п.1 текущим временем

Answer (score 1):

например, так:

```
long prevTime = 0;

private void sumbmit() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    boolean isAction = false;
    synchronized (this) {
        if (currentTime - prevTime > TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)) {
            prevTime = currentTime;
            isAction = true;
        }
    }
    if (isAction) {
        //что то там 
    }
}
```

Comment: Чет не хочет работать. `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)`, 10 это в мс?

Comment: 10 секунд в миллисекундах.